# how come the wordpress admin bar isn't being displayed properly?

Tags: css, wordpress

i just upgraded to wordpress 3.3 and built a really basic template for some reason the wordpress admin bar on the site is displaying really weird. on the backend (dashboard) it is fine though.

i have attached an image, but is there a better way to view my problem? or has anyone else had it?

http://www.keganquimby.com/dev/

it wont let me upload an image, so to see my screen shot: http://www.keganquimby.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Screen-Shot-2011-12-15-at-3.07.29-PM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know you could actually disable the admin bar for the front end of your site altogether, which is what I needed. Clicking on users then toggling the "Show Toolbar when viewing site" option off did it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have already included     `wp_head();`     &     `wp_footer();`

Check function.php for     `show_admin_bar(FALSE);`     and change it to     `show_admin_bar(TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your header.php contains the wp_head(); function call as last line of your head container and that you have wp_footer(); as the last line of your body container?

It's hard to diagnose the issue since your error probably lies server-side (PHP code).

Comment: yeah, its all there. I'm sure its in the PHP, as it looks fine with like twentyeleven. can i send a zip file of the theme?